# Tools to check ajax results/perfomance

Tags: ajax, kohana

I am using ajax heavily on my app and I would like to know if we have a firebug kind of extension that I can use to send calls to it and see results. One sample is an update function, I would like to test if it can return null if someone tries to send a call to it without being logged in and such. I want to be able to test and view results without necessarily coding the whole form with the fetch return kind of architecture. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kohana FirePHP module](https://github.com/kemo/kohana-firephp) (for AJAX profiling) with [Kohana Unittest module](https://github.com/kohana/unittest) will suit your needs

Comment: I need to have both of them of the firephp module will just run? Any "installation steps" available or we do it the Kohana way ;-) DIY!

Comment: @Kenyana: they're both independant